# KOL PBitmap to PJpeg

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am using Delphi7 with the KOL Components and JPegObj.
How can I transfer a PBitmap to PJpeg?

```
var 
 MyBitmap : PBitMap;
 MyJpeg   : PJpeg;
begin
 MyBitMap := ....;
 MyJPeg.Bitmap.Assign (MyBitMap); // ===> Wrong?
 MyJPeg.SaveToFile ('C:\test.jpg');
end;
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Picture here:

[image]

EDIT: My Code:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
 Kol,
 JpegObj;

var
 Jpeg: PJpeg;
 Bitmap: PBitmap;

begin
 Bitmap := NewBitmap(50, 50);
 try
  Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := $0000FF80;
  Bitmap.Canvas.Ellipse(0, 0, 50, 50);
  Jpeg := NewJpeg;
  try
   Jpeg.Bitmap := Bitmap;
   Jpeg.SaveToFile('test.jpg');
  finally
   Jpeg.Free;
  end;
 finally
 Bitmap.Free;
end;
```

Runtime Error 216 at 0041128E

EDIT:
I uncommented the line in JpegObj:

```
 {$DEFINE VER62} // if you plan to use .obj-files from Delphi7 distributive only!
```

Now the program is just frozen.

EDIT: The program freezes here in JpegObj

```
function __ftol: Integer;
 var
  f: double;
begin
 asm
  lea    eax, f             //  BC++ passes floats on the FPU stack
  fstp  qword ptr [eax]     //  Delphi passes floats on the CPU stack
 end;
 Result := Integer(Trunc(f));
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. I edited it. No errors no more. But now the program is frozen...

Comment: So comment the `{$DEFINE}` back out, and **step through the code in the debugger** to see which line causes the error. If you're not going to read requests for more info, you're probably not going to get a lot of help here. :)

Comment: no errors while debugging it with the {$DEFINE} Line... But exception error in the console is : EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 0041626A in module 'Project2.exe'. Read of address 0000003A

Comment: The error is (with the commented    {DEFINE} Line)  : EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 0041626A in module 'Project2.exe'. Read of address 0000003A. I am using Windows7 x86. The Process is allowed to write files to the same path as the project is. (UAC disabled). I use Delphi7 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: The `__ftol` is used *only* in the `JCDCTMGR.OBJ` and `JIDCTFLT.OBJ` files. Were the `*.obj` files part of some KOL package ? If so, could you include the link to that package ? Or if you downloaded them separately, could include that link ?

Comment: http://kolmck.net/kol.zip ---> KOL component. http://kolmck.net/Components/graphics/kolJpegObj.zip ---> JpegObj http://dl.dropbox.com/u/349314/JPegObj.rar ---> *.obj files of my Delphi7 CD. I also found this: http://debian.udsu.ru/pub/soft/win/delphi/delphi/Soft/Delphi7/Info/Extras/Jpeg/obj/

Comment: I give up. :) Twice I've asked you to single-step with the debugger to find the exact line causing the error, and twice you've ignored that and gone off elsewhere (changing a commented `$DEFINE` and `__ftol` out of nowhere). The problem (as indicated by the `0000003A` address) is most likely accessing an object that hasn't been created yet. If you won't provide answers to direct questions, I can't provide any more help. Kudos to @TLama for persistence, and good luck. :)

Comment: my 4th comment [...]no errors while debugging it with the {$DEFINE} Line...[...] @KenWhite I'm sorry.

Comment: Before I try to debug why this happens try to use the `*.obj` files [`from here`](http://hiasm.googlecode.com/svn/elements/delphi/code/JpegObj/), they works for me. I can confirm that I'm getting the access violation with the combination of the following: [`KOL`](http://kolmck.net/kol.zip), [`JpegObj`](http://kolmck.net/Components/graphics/kolJpegObj.zip) and [`OBJ files you've mentioned`](http://debian.udsu.ru/pub/soft/win/delphi/delphi/Soft/Delphi7/Info/Extras/Jpeg/obj/) (they seems to be the Delphi 7's). And don't forget to comment the line with the `{$DEFINE}` directive.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question, because it's turned into a Q&A (question and answer) in the comments. @Benjamin, I'll gladly vote to reopen it if it gets closed if you'll edit it to remove all the non-pertinent information and provide the details you've specifically been asked to provide. (Not downvoting the question - just voting to close because it's all comments asking for more information which isn't forthcoming.)

Comment: With the combination from my last comment I got access violation at call to the `jpeg_start_compress` which is in the `jcapistd.obj` file. So I can only say, don't use the `*.obj` files from Delphi 7 nor from the link you've posted in your last comment, try [`KOL`](http://kolmck.net/kol.zip), [`JpegObj`](http://kolmck.net/Components/graphics/kolJpegObj.zip) and [`OBJ files`](http://hiasm.googlecode.com/svn/elements/delphi/code/JpegObj/). And keep the line with `{$DEFINE}` commented.

Comment: It works now. I got the wrong *.obj files. Thank you so much for your patience and support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Disclaimer: The following has been tested on Delphi 2009!***

You cannot use `PJpeg.Bitmap.Assign` on your `PJpeg` instance because the `PJpeg.Bitmap` is nil at the time you are accessing it since it's not instantiated in `PJpeg` constructor nor later while you were working with that instance. So the attempt to work with the `PJpeg.Bitmap` leads to an access violation.

Try to assign the bitmap this way (it's based on the example from the [`JpegObj`](http://kolmck.net/Components/graphics/kolJpegObj.zip) extension):

```
var 
  MyJpeg: PJpeg;
  MyBitmap: PBitmap;
begin
  // the MyBitMap has a picture assigned here
  MyJpeg := NewJpeg;
  try
    MyJpeg.Bitmap := MyBitmap;
    MyJpeg.SaveToFile('c:\test.jpg');
  finally
    MyJpeg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Here is a VCL minimalistic demo:

```
uses
  KOL, JPEGObj;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Jpeg: PJpeg;
  Bitmap: PBitmap;
begin
  Bitmap := NewBitmap(50, 50);
  try
    Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := $0000FF80;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Ellipse(0, 0, 50, 50);
    Jpeg := NewJpeg;
    try
      Jpeg.Bitmap := Bitmap;
      Jpeg.SaveToFile('c:\image.jpg');
    finally
      Jpeg.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And the amazing result :-)

[image]

Here is another, console minimalistic demo:

```
program Console;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, KOL, JPEGObj;

var
  Jpeg: PJpeg;
  Bitmap: PBitmap;    
begin
  try
    Bitmap := NewBitmap(50, 50);
    try
      Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := $0000CCFF;
      Bitmap.Canvas.Ellipse(0, 0, 50, 50);
      Jpeg := NewJpeg;
      try
        Jpeg.Bitmap := Bitmap;
        Jpeg.SaveToFile('c:\image.jpg');
      finally
        Jpeg.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Bitmap.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

And the exciting result :-)

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for me. It crashes with a runtime error. I don't know why. It creates the file but it has 0bytes

Comment: Try to be more specific, runtime error doesn't tell me anything. I bet you are getting the access violation, but first try the *minimalistic demo* from this post.

Comment: I tried both examples from you but doesn't work. The runtime error appears for 1ms in the console window... EDIT: I edited the first post.